# Is the ID of a RTCDataChannels global or specific to a RTCPeerConnection?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, webrtc

Is the ID of a RTCDataChannels global or specific to a RTCPeerConnection?

Eg, if I have a p1 and p2, two peer connections, can I create a data channel on each that has id 7, or will they collide?

I have tried this on Chrome with the webrtc shim, an it appears that ids are specific to a RTCPeerConnection. I can't, however, find where in the spec this is specified...

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The id comes from the transport layer of the connection. It's a number between 0 and 65534, and is unique only to that connection (the pair of RTCPeerConnections communicating).

See "Stream Identifier" in section 3 of https://www.ietf.org/id/draft-ietf-rtcweb-data-protocol-09.txt

There's a workaround however. You're allowed to specify your own id with [`createDataChannel`](http://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/#dom-rtcpeerconnection-createdatachannel):

```
let channel = createDataChannel("foo", { id: 3 });
```

So you could use localStorage to keep them unique for your app (up to a point of course) if that's what you want.

In other words, you don't have to worry about collisions between RTCPeerConnections, unless they're the two ends of the same connection.